# How to store international languages string in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, unicode

I have two columns in a table and source database contain ???? and special characters for name which has values other than English.My source database is in ms sql server and my target database is postgresql. Can I recover those values to their real values when i'm loading data.

Comment: Note: good English writing requires more characters than just ASCII or Latin-1. You should know the original data encoding, the encoding the client ask from the database, and how you set the encoding in postgtreesql. Often it is easier (to you and to write question) to put a fake column with non-ASCII character (and then with non Latin-1/"ANSI" character), and check output on every step. We need more data to help you.

Comment: Actually the original data contains ???? for arabic characters.Is there anyway to convert them back to what ever language it was entered.

Comment: 1-Are you sure that original data contains `???`? Is it just your client which cannot read such data (or database that transform the data in the encoding of your client)? 2- If the database has not information, you cannot retrieve it, but I would carefully check p1. Force all to UTF-8. 3- you need to put a new column with non-ASCII, and then also non Latin-1 and read such data. "Arabic" is too generic. you need a precise character, and so the precise code in db, and when you read. First step you need to understand all encoding transformations in your workflow. Only later with existing data.

Comment: yes original data is stored in that way. even the database owner doesn't know waht were the actually value that user has entered.so can't we get the real value?

Comment: I'm not sure. If I understand correctly, the program which wrote to the database did the encoding conversion, putting `???`. Blame the programmer. It seems strange that the database discarded (without errors/warning) such conversion, and 8-bit strings were common, so you may had wrong characters (so recoverable) instead of `???`. Good news for you: now the world is Unicode, so such problems/errors will disappear soon.

Comment: yea programmer didn't use encoding conversion